# Python: text matching

Tags: python, string, iteration

I have a database that looks like this:

```
df['col'] = ['text', 'Texts', 'Text-Pro', 'Text;Nothing', 'Pro', 'pro', 'Pros', 'Nothing']
```

What I want to do is iterate, and find these values, but it's not working:

```
for i in range(len(df['col']):
   if df.loc[i, 'col'] in list(['text', 'pro']):
   print('yes')
```

The output that I want:

```
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
```

Comment: Hi it seems your code sample is mis-formatted (indentation of `print`) and will not run as is. Is this what is "not working", or what exactly is the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below should what you ask. Note that I re-structured some items, to work better with your DataFrame. (I assume based on your code you are working with pandas).

```
import pandas

# outsource the matching to a function so we can use `map` below
def match_string(input_string):
    """
    """
    target_strings = ['text', 'pro']
    for target in target_strings:
        # you need to lower your strings if you want the match to be case-insensitive
        if target in input_string.lower():
            print("yes")
            return "yes"
    print("no")
    return "no"

df = pandas.DataFrame()

df['col'] = ['text', 'Texts', 'Text-Pro', 'Text;Nothing', 'Pro', 'pro', 'Pros', 'Nothing']
# instead of iterating, use a map operation which is much more efficient
# this will store the result in the column 'string_matched' as well as print it out as the question requests
df["string_matched"] = df["col"].map(lambda x: match_string(x))
```

You can find some documentation around the pandas map [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

Output

```
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
no
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You basically need to check for `'text'` or `'pro'` in the columns. So, you should compare those 2 strings **with** the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = ['text', 'Texts', 'Text-Pro', 'Text;Nothing', 'Pro', 'pro', 'Pros', 'Nothing']
list1=[]
for i in range(len(df['col'])):
    
    if  'text' in str(df['col'][i]).lower() or 'pro' in str(df['col'][i]).lower():
        list1.append("yes")
    else:
        list1.append("no")
df['Test/Pro']=list1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            col Test/Pro
0          text      yes
1         Texts      yes
2      Text-Pro      yes
3  Text;Nothing      yes
4           Pro      yes
5           pro      yes
6          Pros      yes
7       Nothing       no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and boolean masking. You may need to update the regex to match your use case.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['col'] = ['text', 'Texts', 'Text-Pro', 'Text;Nothing', 'Pro', 'pro', 'Pros', 'Nothing']

masking = df['col'].str.contains(r'(Text|text)|(Pro|pro)')

print(masking)
```

prints

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the comparison with the 2 required strings when iterating over the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = ['text', 'Texts', 'Text-Pro', 'Text;Nothing', 'Pro', 'pro', 'Pros', 'Nothing']

for i in range(len(df['col'])):
    if  'PRO' in str(df['col'][i]).upper() or 'TEXT' in str(df['col'][i]).upper():
            print("yes")
    else:
            print("no")
```

Output

```
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
yes
no
```